# Should parameterless async workflows in F# be wrapped in functions?

Tags: f#

If I've got an async *parameterless* workflow in F#, is it necessary and/or idiomatic to make that a function, or is it best left as a raw value?

For example if I want to define `getRemoteCounterAfterOneSec`, polls some remote counter source, should it be

```
let getRemoteCounterAfterOneSec = 
  async {
    do! Async.Sleep 1000
    return! ...
  }
```

or

```
let getRemoteCounterAfterOneSec () = 
  async {
    do! Async.Sleep 1000
    return! ...
  }
```

It *seems* like they should do the same thing, just the latter has an unnecessary parameter.  However I've seen this done both ways in various code.  I've also seen places where the behavior ends up different: if using a `MailboxProcessor` and doing

```
let myFunc = mailboxProc.PostAndAsyncReply(fun reply -> GetCount reply)
async {
  let! count1 = myFunc
  let! count2 = myFunc
}
```

then the mailboxProcessor is only called once; the second time it merely returns the same value calculated in the previous call.  However if `myFunc` is a function then it calls mailboxProcessor twice as you'd expect.

```
let myFunc() = mailboxProc.PostAndAsyncReply(fun reply -> GetCount reply)
async {
  let! count1 = myFunc()
  let! count2 = myFunc()
}
```

Is that a bug in the implementation?  What's going on here and what is idiomatic?

Comment: keep the version without the `()` - you don't need it and there is no reason to rebuild the async-wf every time you want to use it here

Comment: in your other example the thing is, that you of course create your message for the processor only once and send it at once (when calling `PostAndAsyncReply`) - the resulting workflow just waits for this one query to return - so here it makes sense to build a new workflow every time you want to use it

Comment: remember: F# is still strict ;)

Comment: You can change the `let myFunc = mailboxProc.PostAndAsyncReply(fun reply -> GetCount reply)` to `let myFunc = async { return! mailboxProc.PostAndAsyncReply(fun reply -> GetCount reply) }` to keep the laziness without introducing the extra parameter.

Comment: Or `let myFunc = async.ReturnFrom(mailboxProc.PostAndAsyncReply(fun reply -> GetCount reply))`

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to ordinary asyncs that you define yourself, then adding `()` has no effect (well, it means that the async that *describes a computation* is constructed repeatedly, but it has no practical effect).

I sometimes write it just to make my code easier to understand, or when the async is recursive (because then you get a warning when you have a recursive value). So, the following is fine, but it gives you a warning:

```
let rec loop = 
  async {
    do! Async.Sleep 1000
    if 1 > 2 then return 1
    else return! loop }
```

The `PostAndAsyncReply` method is written a bit differently - and the name tries to reflect that. Normal F# async methods are named `AsyncFooBar`. This one has `PostAndAsyncFooBar` to indicate that it *first* posts and then asynchronously waits, that is something like:

```
let PostAndAsyncWait () =
  post(message)
  async { let! sth = wait ()
          return sth }
```

So, here it actually posts outside of the async - this lets you call the function even if you are (syntactically) outside of an `async` block. And the name tries to be very explicit about this.
(But I would personally prefer if it was all inside async i.e. `AsyncPostAndWait`).